# One-to-Many Relationship displayed as ajax result

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax

I have two table `department` and `city`

```
city ( #id (PK) , name , id_department (FK) , ... ) 
department( #id (PK) , name , ... )
```

and I make an Ajax call to display all departments and their cities.

I run this query :

```
select distinct d.id , d.nom , c.id , c.nom 
from department d 
left join city c on d.id = c.id_department
```

The problem is that I got one department repeated in many rows because I have one to many relationship .

The question is what is the best, cleanest and easiest way to display the query result with Ajax in Javascript / jQuery with `$.each()` loop?

How to handle them and display them in my html page?

I want display them as checkbox tree in a popup and the user check what he want to do a search operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "such thing" ?

Comment: I think OP refers "such thing" as **without duplicate rows**

Comment: If the query is incorrect, I'd suggest fixing that instead of having the *UI* to fix what is essentially a data issue.  What *RMDBS* are you using?

Comment: no the query is correct and it's normal to get repeated departement because i have one to many relationship

Comment: *the probleme is that I got one departments repeated in many rows because i have one to many relationship*, sounds like a data issue, so I still think you need to alter the query.  Are you using **SQL Server**, if so, what version?

Comment: i want get department  and its cities so the query is correct i think... i'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.id, d.nom, c.id, c.nom from department d, city c
where d.id = c.id_departement
```

unless you need to explicit the joint you can try this query.